# How does one access the crashreporter files to delete on the iPad

Tags: ipad, crash, crash-reports

How does one access the crashreporter files to delete on the iPad if it is not rooted / jail-broken?

I need to purge the contents because it is full

.... ReportCrash[114] : Failed to save memory report to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2014-03-07-135429.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, euid: 0 egid: 0. 100 logs already present.

Already searched and only came across this old unanswered Question:

[Access Crashreporter Files in App iOs 5 Enterprise Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930760/access-crashreporter-files-in-app-ios-5-enterprise-application)

and this one

[How Can I Delete iOS Crash Reporter Logs Off the Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869038/how-can-i-delete-ios-crash-reporter-logs-off-the-device)
which needs to be jail-broken to work

Comment: iPhone Configuration Utility would do that, Xcode would do it as well. Ow, and this question is rather close to being off-topic, by the way.

Comment: Try [that one](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/crash/) ;)

Comment: Till: in iPhone Configuration Utility, i get these tabs: Summary, Configuration profiles, Provisioning profiles, Applications, Console. Console only allows me to view the console log and save contents. So how do i access files on the iPad using the utility?    Why is it close to being off-topic? I thought i started a new topic?

Comment: HAS: your link goes to the Developer page, i accept the terms but then get an error:The webpage at https://developer.apple.com/register/completeRegistration.action?cancelURL=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fprograms&successURL=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fbug-reporting%2Fios%2Fcrash%2F has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: HAS: OK link did not work because it needed to verify my developer registration email. Once that was done. page loads ok [link]https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/crash/ but it only talks about retrieval of crash logs - not how to delete. Anyway found if I enable Auto Sending to Apple diagnostic info then i am able to save new crash reports - obviously it is not cycling the reports keeping last 100.

Comment: @sa2012 Well it does (indirectly): as soon as you synch your device with iTunes it copies the crash logs to your Mac/PC and deletes them on the device.

Comment: And maybe take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869038/how-can-i-delete-ios-crash-reporter-logs-off-the-device)

Comment: Thank you - perfect. Don't know why i did not come across that answer. Edit: I did come across it. I ignored it because it said move reports to the trash and that was not possible for me. Anyway thanks for the help. all ok now - apart from the fact that iPad 1 gets loads of low memory crashes !!!!